# EU tax regulation and Invoice number based on delivery country

Tags: magento, invoice

The EU tax law requires that if a company bills over a certain amount in a certian country, it needs to open a VAT in that country and invoice customers of that country with that VAT number.
Magento do provide the possibility to set different TAX rules according to the destination country, but neither Magento and all Magento Connect extensions, do provide custom invoice numbers according to the destination country.
Is it possible to customize invoice number basing on shipping country and not on Magento storeview?
If not, what should be the best steps to achieve such result?

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this with store views for that country and then by overriding the admin config options for that store. Consider this. In the UK, the VAT rate is 20% but in Ireland it is 23%. I don't want my customers in Ireland to get a nasty shock when viewing the prices on the product page at 20% and then as soon as they enter there address, it changes to 23% and all product prices change.

We resolved this by creating separate store views (This gives you ability to have different invoice numbers per store view for invoices). It also means customers see correct price on product pages and category list pages based upon your vat settings. Do the same for non EU countries so they see prices excluding VAT throughout the site. I then built a GEO IP extension to lookup the country the user is browsing our site from, and redirect them to the appropriate store view if they so wish. You can also have different URL's for store views so it's entirely possible to have shop.com and shop.ie and shop.de etc. If you later wish to translate your site per store view you have everything ready to go.

Other option is to modify the invoice block and phtml files to take the delivery country into account and display your VAT number accordingly, but for the reasons identified above, I personally would do it with store views.

Comment: GEO IP is a good solution but it means i must make a storeview for every country? The problem is the the EU tax law wants invoice basing on shipping country and not on purchase country. Can happend that someone buys from Switzerland on the italian or german or french storeview. That's the reason why it will be great to find a procedure to add a country code (like the ISO code) as a prefix but then every country must have it's own counter. If i make 19 storeview Magento will collaps :)

Comment: I have 8 store views and magento is perfectly fine. I don't have one for every country, only the ones registered for VAT in because it's over the threshold. There are many advantages for store views, but I must confess we do not use Magento's Invoicing system, our back office handles the VAT number according to the destination it is being delivered in much like you want and produces the invoice to go in the order. When you say "Is it possible to customize invoice number" do you mean put the country specific VAT number on the invoice or are you referring to the Invoice increment ID's?

Comment: Customize Increment ID's and Prefix based on shipping addres country.
Maybe is possible to modify some Magento Class , but i think i must add also another table to manage id's and prefixs. 
Something like:
If the order is to ship to Italy it must be IT-000001
If the order is to ship to United Kingdom it must be UK-00001

Storeview can't ensure this .. may be with the GEO IP solution.
Otherways is there any easy invoicing program that can do this and connect to Magento?